# My Android Takeaway app won't fill subject and body text in Gmail but works with Outlook

Tags: android, email, outlook, gmail

I have created an Android takeaway ordering app in Android Studio which is supposed to send an order by email and fill in subject and text body fields. It does this when I send by Outlook but refuses to fill these fields when I use Android G mail client on emulator, mobile phone (Android 10) and tablet (Android 7) – it just sends a blank email.

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    submit_order_quantity = submit_order_quantity + 1;
    EditText enterName = findViewById(R.id.nameBar);
    String showName = enterName.getText().toString(); //gets you the contents of name edit text
    EditText enterTelephone = findViewById(R.id.your_telephone);
    String showPhone = enterTelephone.getText().toString(); //gets you the contents of telephone number edit text
    EditText enterTime = findViewById(R.id.collect_time);
    String showTime = enterTime.getText().toString(); //gets you the contents of telephone number edit text


    double totalPrice = calculatePrice();
    String priceMessage = createOrderSummary(showName, showPhone, showTime, totalPrice);

    if(submit_order_quantity == 1 && totalPrice != 0){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto",         "emailaddress@email.com", null));
        // only email apps should handle this
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, Restaurant Order for: + showName);
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, priceMessage);
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email..."));
    }
}
```

Takeaway order app.

showName is toString result of EditText enterName

showPhone is toString result of EditText enterTelephone

showTime is toString result of EditText enterTime

totalPrice is result of price of items multiplied by the quantity of each as a series of Strings to create  priceMessage

The Manifest:-

```
 <queries>

     <!--
     Specific intents you query for,
     eg: for a custom share UI
-->
     <intent>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
         <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
     </intent>
     <intent>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
         <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
     </intent>
     <intent>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
         <data android:scheme="mailto" />
     </intent>
     <intent>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
         <data android:scheme="mailto" />
     </intent>
     <intent>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
         <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
     </intent>
     <intent>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
         <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
     </intent>
     <intent>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
         <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google.panorama360+jpg"/>
     </intent>
     <intent>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
         <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>

     </intent>
     <intent>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
         <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
     </intent>

 </queries>

 <application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:fullBackupContent="@xml/my_backup_rules"
     android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_logo_round"
     android:supportsRtl="true"
     android:theme="@style/Theme.TakeawayFood">
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <data android:mimeType="message/rfc822" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity
         android:name=".Starters"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
         <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
         <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
             android:value=".MainActivity" />
     </activity>
     <activity
         android:name=".Mains"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
         <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
         <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
             android:value=".MainActivity" />
     </activity>
     <activity
         android:name=".Desserts"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
         <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
         <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
             android:value=".MainActivity" />
     </activity>
 </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your intent like this, this worked for my app to share to Gmail:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"emailaddress@email.com"});
...
```